# Capifony php error

Tags: php, symfony, capistrano, capifony

I in the past weeks I have a problem with capifony... So I have made the deploy.rb and it was not a problem:

```
set :application, "Infinity"
set :domain,      "xxx"
set :deploy_to,   "/var/www/inf.sitetester.biz"
set :app_path,    "app"

set :repository,  "D:/work/test.inf.serv"
set :scm,         :git
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `subversion`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, or `none`
set   :deploy_via,    :copy
set :model_manager, "doctrine"
# Or: `propel`

role :web,        domain                         # Your HTTP server,    Apache/etc
role :app,        domain, :primary => true       # This may be the same as your `Web` server

set  :keep_releases,  3
ssh_options[:port] = "xx"
set :user, "xxx"
set :use_composer, false
```

After this I have made:

```
cap deploy:setup
```

And after the setup

```
cap deploy
```

Here is the output
[image]

I cannot understand why the cache warmup is generating those kind of errors. Is someone familiar with this?